# url rewriting in my web site

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I  found that my site's server [software] is Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) FrontPage/5.0.2.2635.  IS it possible to use rewrite url using .htaccess in my site?  Is it apache server ? Does any one please provide how to do thisclean url in my site .

Comment: You have to provide what you want to exactly achieve.

Comment: `I found that my site's server [software] is Apache/2.2.14 (...) Is it apache server ?` Looks like it, doesn' it? ;)

Comment: If you want to start with .htaccess, there are tons of free resources about it on the net (i.e. http://goo.gl/uQoQM). And, sure you can use it with Apache (it IS Apache server)! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check that in the  tag of your document root of apache config `AllowOverride` is set to `On`, and the apache module `mod_rewrite` should be activated. Please add more details about your system and we can show you how to setup/activate it.

Comment: In my local system I got .httpd.conf file from the Apache folder. Here I have changed AllowOverride is On. And rewrite URL is working fine in my local system. But I don't know from where I will get .httpd file for my web site. While uploading files to the server I got only the .htdocs and cgi-bin folder. Please answer me ..

Comment: often the .httaccess is hidden in the FTP programs. upload it with the name dummy.htaccess and then rename it on the server into .htaccess.